Build and deploy ASP.NET 4.6.x website in DevOps Pipelines and deploy to Azure VM
I have an ASP.NET 4.6.1 website that I've moved to a Windows 2019 server. Unfortunately, updating the website past ASP.NET 4.6.1 isn't an option at the moment.
My Visual Studio solution contains 1 web app and 1 class library project.  The web app references the class library project.
The solution builds and runs as expected. The questions I have are regarding build and deployment using DevOps Pipelines.  I'm looking for the proper way to do this because what I've done feels like a hack (and takes forever). Since ASP.NET isn't too popular any longer, most of the articles I've found are from 5 or more years ago and don't appear to work with the latest versions of DevOps.
Here is an abbreviated version of what my pipeline looks like:
BUILD
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:PackageAsSingleFile=false /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" /p:TransformWebConfigEnabled=true /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false /p:MarkWebConfigAssistFilesAsExclude=true /p:IsTransformWebConfigDisabled=false'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(devBuildConfiguration)'
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'CMSDevBuildOutput'

DEPLOY
         - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
           inputs: 
             source: 'current'
             artifact: 'CMSDevBuildOutput'
             path: 'CMSDevPublish'
         - task: CopyFiles@2
           inputs: 
            SourceFolder: 'CMSDevPublish/Archive/Content/D_C/a/1/s/Portal/SourceCode/CMS/obj/$(devBuildConfiguration)/Package/PackageTmp'
            Contents: '**'
            TargetFolder: 'H:\Websites\Portal\$(Build.BuildId)'

What I don't like is in the CopyFiles@2 SourceFolder parameter.  It's like this because the msbuild is NOT packaging it as a single file.  I've not done this because when I tried it initially it packages each of the projects in the solution into separate .zip files and I'm unsure of how to unpackaged both of those into the proper folders on the server.
So my question is how do I properly use MSBUILD to build AND package a multi-project solution THEN properly deploy it to a VM so IIS is ready to consume it.

The app deployment files are generated in build job, you can publish as a single package(/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true) or not as you do now, both are fine.
When you deploy to local IIS, you are only copy the files to the IIS folder, it's recommended to use the IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0 for the deployment instead. You can specify package to the single zip package or files folder.
Before the deployment, you can use task IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0  to stop, create or update the web app, and start it after the deployment if needed.
Please check the link for your reference.

@wade-zhou-msft This is helpful, however, we are deploying to a build folder ID in IIS and managing the IIS instance to point to that new build folder ID we published to which is another reason we used CopyFiles@2.  The folder for the website is set like so: TargetFolder: 'H:\Websites\Portal\$(Build.BuildId)'  So every deployment we have a new folder with the build ID we publish to.  Doesn't seem I can can do with with IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0

Both the artifact content and deployment target folder can be controlled, you can create or delete the ID folder with a pre-task if needed. The copy task only stores the files, but not manages the IIS. It's recommended to use the two IIS tasks. But if you prefer copy task, make sure the IIS can have the new files, and update/start successfully, which typically achieved by IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0 task.
